# Rails to install sliding doors

Tags: doors, closet

I’m including a picture of the sliding doors I need to install. I’m also including pics of the previous installation.

So my question: what’s the name of the *rails* (if that’s the correct *word*) for installing these doors?

Is there an easier way to install these?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those doors appear to be a 4 fold "Bifold" door set and are not called sliding doors. Sliding doors are more typically "Bypass" doors or a "Barn" type door.

It does look like you are in need of a hardware replacement but armed with your pictures, measurements, and the proper name most hardware stores should be able to sell you a suitable replacement.

EDIT-As for an easier installation- If you can, I suggest making 2 pair of 2 doors that open from the middle towards both sides. Bifold door hardware is pretty "lightweight" and often will want to pop out of the track- especially when you are folding all 4 doors to one side- It is just pretty unwieldy.

Just a note, It seems that 3 of the 4 doors are installed upside down. The louvers should orient high on the inside of the closet and angle forward and down. The third door from the left is properly oriented and the other 3 are upside down.

Comment: If you compare the top rails it looks like 2 are upside-down and one is inside-out - lol. Not a lot of attention to detail went into that installation.

Answer (score 0):

This [amazon link](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=bifold%20door%20replacement%20hardware&gclid=Cj0KCQjwl92XBhC7ARIsAHLl9amqvo1iDm2ZMByMsEfIakMC5ZfkFnLPibSlAg-FFTks2IiL7jOTrG0aAqBAEALw_wcB&hvadid=267917081733&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9003047&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=6573287457819785059&hvtargid=kwd-445351882743&hydadcr=8167_9885028&tag=googhydr-20&ref=pd_sl_69muuovv6a_e) has several types of replacement hardware.  the rails or track as more commonly called are made for 3 different types of pin hardware.

---

You have a single wheel track like what is shown in the picture.

There is a thinner pin style track where a nylon pin is sticking up in the track.

Last is the hanging multi wheel track.

I have seen a few with bottom tracks as well but that is rare as people don't like a bottom groove or to step on the track.

---

A great deal of the new hardware now is spring loaded so you just push the pins down and then it will slide in to place. If that is not possible and your doors are not hinged in place yet you can tilt them sideways when they are closed to get the hardware under the track.

---

I personally prefer the bi-fold doors over sliding doors when you don't have the ability to use pocket doors. since the sliding doors don't have a hinge attached to a wall they tend to derail more frequently in my experience and can be a real pain to put back on the track. also depending on the opening size you may not have the room to put sliding door hardware in place.